# Error message with pg_dump and PostgreSQL 14

Tags: postgresql, bash, ubuntu, pg-dump

We use PostgreSQL for our database of [Speedy Net](https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net). I had a production server with PostgreSQL 13, and I backed up my database with the following command:

```
pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost "speedy_net" | gzip > <file_name>.sql.gz
```

It worked with PostgreSQL 13, but recently I upgraded my server to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and PostgreSQL 14. I loaded the database from SQL and everything works properly, but now I can't backup the database - I get the following error message:

```
pg_dump: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: fe_sendauth: no password supplied
```

Now, something has changed in the configuration file from PostgreSQL 13 to 14. In PostgreSQL 13, the file `/etc/postgresql/13/main/pg_hba.conf` was:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 md5
```

And in PostgreSQL 14 the file `/etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf` is:

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             speedy_net                              trust

# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

Notice, the line `local   all             speedy_net                              trust` is new. Is this line causing problems? I had to add it because otherwise I couldn't load the database from SQL.

Do you know how I fix it so that backups will work? If I run the command `pg_dump -U postgres -h localhost "speedy_net"` manually I get prompted for password, but there is no password and it worked with PostgreSQL 13.

Maybe I need to change the password? How do I do it?

Comment: I think you'd better ask this to https://serverfault.com/

Comment: @F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub You are correct, but I already asked here and got an answer, and I don't want to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line that is causing the problems in the new file is

```
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
```

That requires you to supply a password. You have two choices:

- Use a different authentication method.  `trust` would allow you to login without a password (since you are using it with “localhost” in IPv4, why not with IPv6?). If you don't want that, certificate authentication would be an option.
- Create a [password file](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-pgpass.html) on the new machine. Since you forced password authentication on the old machine, that's probably what you used there.

Comment: Thank you, I changed it to `trust`. Since we trust the localhost on IPv4, we should also trust it with IPv6. I think the old server didn't use IPv6.